Find text between characters using regular expressions
I need to find the FIRST text between the symbols: '[' and ']>'. However, it seems that I get the text between the first symbol '[' and the last symbols ']>'.
    ' Create the regular expression.
Set regEx = New RegExp
regEx.IgnoreCase = True
regEx.MultiLine = False
regEx.Global = False

regEx.Pattern = "(?=\[)(.*)(?=\]\>)"

If regEx.Test(myRng) Then
    Set Matches = regEx.Execute(myRng)
    xStr_2 = Matches(0).FirstIndex + 1
    myStr_2 = Matches(0)
Else
    xStr_2 = 0
    myStr_2 = "


Make the dot lazy: (?=\[)(.*?)(?=\]\>)

You may just use \[(.*?)\]>. Or, \[([^[]*?)\]> if no [ should appear between [ and ]>. Well, you wull still have problems with [ and ] inside the CDATA, they are serialized, so you will still need to run 2 replace commands to actually safely get the text only value from CDATA.

Thank you, Wiktor! Both of your options will work.
